# Can't Access Child JSON Element of JSON Payload with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I've got this script up, I intentionally replaced some parts of the code with a series of Xs to censor any secure information.

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");

var SessionID = DataExtension.Init("XXXX");
var Points = DataExtension.Init("XXXXXX");  
var data = SessionID.Rows.Retrieve();
var dataDE = data.length -1;
var datas = data[dataDE];
var accessToken = datas.Codefrom;
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
var pointsdata = Points.Rows.Retrieve();
  
for (var i=0; i<pointsdata.length; i++) {
    var pointdata=pointsdata[i];
    var cardNumber=pointdata.card_number;
    var transactionId=pointdata.transaction_id;
    var pointValue=pointdata.PointValue;
    var contentType='application/json';
    var url='https://ENDPOINTHERE.com/';
  
       var payload={
         "PointValue": pointValue,
         "ProgramGuid":"a2fe52ae-d382-440d-ada3-c9a32ddd5d26",
         "Reward":1,
         "CardNumber":cardNumber,
         "SessionGuid":accessToken,
         "TransactionMetadataDescription":"TEST DELETE THIS"
     }
       
     var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
     req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
     req.retries = 2;
     req.continueOnError = true;
     req.contentType = "application/json"
     req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
     req.method = "POST";
     req.postData = Stringify(payload);
 
     var resp = req.send();

     var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));

  
 var childResult=Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resultJSON[0].Result));
 
  var status=childResult[0].Status;
  
  Write(status);

     var brokertransactionId=resultJSON.brokerTransactionId;
  

  Write(brokertransactionId);




}

</script>
```

This is the example payload I'm getting back from the HTTPRequest that I made:

```
{"Result":{"Message":"","MessageDetails":"","Status":1},"brokerTransactionId":14418728}
```

This is the specific line in question that is throwing errors, everything else works as intended

```
 var childResult=Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resultJSON[0].Result));
 
  var status=childResult[0].Status;
```

I would like to extract Message, MessageDetails, and Status from the Result object. I have been able to extract the brokerTransactionId from the response, but nothing else in the Result JSON payload.

I thought I doing a ParseJSON on the child Result element would allow me to access the JSON object but I keep getting hit with a 500 Error. I also tried a try catch statement around the line that's throwing the errors

Comment: `var status=childResult[0].Status` -> the [0] implies that `childResult` were an Array, which would look like a list enclosed in square brackets. Like so: `[{"Message":"","MessageDetails":"","Status":1},{"Message":"","MessageDetails":"","Status":2}]`  . Here you would use `childResult[0]`  to "get into the square brackets / array", and retrieve the first (aka 0th) element. However, your `childResult` is just an object, enclosed in { }: `{"Message":"","MessageDetails":"","Status":1}`. To get "into the curly brackets / object", you should be fine with `childResult.Status`, skipping the [0] part.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I actually started with just childResult.Status, still getting 500 error. Any other ideas whats going on here?

Comment: Based on the information provided by you, the answer from Jonas is your solution to the problem. If you see 500 errors you should start debugging your response. Use a try/catch around the entire for loop to see what is throwing the error. You also do not need to do parseJSON again on the resultJSON: resultJSON.Result.Message should be enough. Keep in mind JS is case sensetive. Result != result in an object.